# Delimiter change in csv using python

Tags: python, excel, csv, delimiter, import-from-excel

I have a .csv file of around 30000 rows. The default delimiter implemented is a semicolon. I created a small script with python that would convert that delimiter to comma and save it in the same file. The script runs without any errors but does nothingnat the end. The delimiter is still a semicolon. The .txt file is created but it does not write back on the main file. The code I am using is as follows:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()  # Get the current working directory (cwd)
files = os.listdir(cwd)  # Get all the files in that directory
print("Files in %r: %s" % (cwd, files))

with open('RadGridExport.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, dialect="excel")
    with open('temp.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(reader)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the delimiter while reading. By default it looks for comma, since it is not the case you have to specify the delimiter:

```
  reader = csv.reader(infile, dialect="excel",delimiter=";")
```

And you need not mention comma as delimiter while writing since it is the default.

Or the easiest way is to use pandas package:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.read_csv(infile,sep=';')
    df.to_csv(infile,index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But it still does not do anything. I tried creating another demo csv file but it is not the problem with the csv file. Still debugging the solution